# Combination of VAE with GAN

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, variational-autoencoder

I am going to implement a lecture which it aims to generate new images. It uses a variational autoencoder to produce latent vector and then feed it to a gan network as input. My question is, in variational autoencoder each dimension of latent vector is sampled from a different gussian distribution  (sigma,mu). But I guess the generator in gan, gets input from one gussian distribution, so the input is sampled from one sigma,mu pair. So,is this idea really sensible? Or I understood the input of gan wrongly?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement a lecture"?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is very similar to [VAE-GAN](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2019/0584.pdf). Take a look at the paper.

From what I remember from it, I think they couple a VAE to a GAN discriminator, which is functionally very similar to coupling a VAE encoder to a GAN, as the VAE decoder and GAN generator have lots of similarities.